How to restart a process if it gets killed in Red Hat Linux?
I have developed a streamlit app that might need all the resources when being used. Since its a demo app, the process gets killed sometimes when the user is playing around without giving the app some processing time.
How can I check that the process is running, if it breaks, run "streamlit run app.py" atuomatically.
The app is running on red hat linux.
I can use crontab one liners.
I came accross the following snippet (ps auxw | grep -iq "path_to_python path_tostreamlit/streamlit run app.py") || streamlit run path_to_file/app.py
I am not sure if this helps.

Have another process, a supervisor, who restarts if the process is dying. Most often that's systemd nowadays. Developer can use a user-controlled systemd, while deployed application typically is using it (or another service control daemon) in a traditional, system-controlled way.

You're not providing much background info, e.g. how does it get started initially? Typically these days you launch daemons and apps via systemd; and while you're using RedHat, not raspian, have a look at this question over at stackoverflow ... it might just address your own problem - note the restart: always which should nicely fit your bill. the cron every minute might leave you with a 59 second gap, systemd restart should be instantaneous.

This might help: Re-run an application script when it crashes?
